# LIBGDX: How do you horizontally/vertically flip a camera view?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to create a four way symmetric program that has 1 camera viewing a specific scene, but just flipping the view of the camera for each of the 4 panels.

For example: [symmetry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg0jZ.png)

Quadrant 1 would be the regular orientation of the world with positive x to the right and positive y upwards. 
Quadrant 2 would be positive x to the left and positive y upwards, and so on.

I've figured out a way to draw the same camera view in multiple panels by starting and ending my spritebatch multiple times (not sure if this is a bad thing but it's the way I got it to work) and changing the glViewport of each panel.

```
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    batch.begin();        
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();

    batch.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();        

    batch.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();

    batch.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
```

I think a linear transformation would do it but I haven't worked with libgdx or linear algebra enough to see an immediate clear answer.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

**Flipping the camera**

Keep a matrix around for doing the flips without messing with the camera.

```
private final Matrix4 tmpM = new Matrix4();
```

Then you can flip it for the three flipped quadrants:

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
batch.begin();        
batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
batch.end();

Gdx.gl.glViewport(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
batch.setProjectionMatrix(tmpM.set(cam.combined).scl(1, -1, 1));
batch.begin();        
batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
batch.end();

Gdx.gl.glViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
batch.setProjectionMatrix(tmpM.set(cam.combined).scl(-1, -1, 1));
batch.begin();        
batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
batch.end();

Gdx.gl.glViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
batch.setProjectionMatrix(tmpM.set(cam.combined).scl(-1, -1, 1));
batch.begin();        
batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
batch.end();
```

**FrameBuffer**

If your scene is complex, this may be faster because the actual scene is drawn only one time. Create your frame buffer object in resize. The try/catch is because some old or budget phones don't support RGBA8888 color in a frame buffer object.

```
public void resize (int width, int height){
    if (frameBuffer != null) frameBuffer.dispose();
    try {
        frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, width/2, height/2, false); 
    } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
        frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB565, width/2, height/2, false);
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
frameBuffer.begin();
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
batch.begin();        
batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
batch.end();
frameBuffer.end();

Texture fbTex = frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture();
batch.getProjectionMatrix().idt();
batch.begin();
batch.draw(fbTex, -1, 1, 1, -1);
batch.draw(fbTex, -1, 0, 1, 1);
batch.draw(fbTex, 0, 0, 1, 1);
batch.draw(fbTex, 0, 1, 1, -1);
batch.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flip [TextureRegion](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html) by using

```
    void flip(boolean x, boolean y);
```

method just before `batch.draw()`.

If your `img` is Texture instance you can *cast* it to TextureRegion one by using following constructor

```
    public TextureRegion(Texture texture)
```